# Access - Data Provider Not Initialised?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have used Access 2003 to develop a frontend to a SQL Server database. Because the system was intended to use different Schemas to partition the table data, an Access Project did not work. So, instead, I am forced to take over the connection management for access - I maintain a global connection object, and assign recordsets to Forms rather than recordsources.

One issue this causes - any time someone tries to use built-in Access functionality that interacts with the recordset, the operation doesn't work, and a dialog box is displayed saying 'Data Provider could not be initialised'. I've done some research, and have been unable to find a relevant cause for this, but I suspect it's due to Access expecting a Form to have a proper recordsource property, and does not really work with assigned recordsets.

Anyone able to shed any more light on this one? Is there a way to use self-managed recordsets, AND make use of built-in functionality? Can anyone confirm this is an Access bug?

Comment: What type of recordset are you assigning to the form: ADO or DAO?  If ADO, which provider are you using?  What's the recordset's type, its options (e.g., dynamic, static, forward-only, etc.).

Comment: Why fight Access? Just create ODBC linked tables and work with those, which are very reliable. Sure, there are some cases where they will be inefficient, in which case you work around it by using passthroughs or moving the logic server-side. Trying to go the unbound route just makes no sense when ODBC is so easy. It is, in fact, MS's currently recommended best practice for development of front ends to run against SQL Server.

Comment: Recordsets are ADO, using the MS SQL Server provider (SQL 2005). Options are client-side cursors, Keysets, Read Only.

As for why not linked tables? The designer specifically asked me not to - the users are not to have direct access to the tables for security and practicality reasons...of course, this was only revealed AFTER we had started down the track of using Access (this project really should be in VB.net, not Access, but we're stuck with Access now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some playing around, I found a partial solution. I was using Client-side cursors, but leaving the recordsets connected. By instead disconnecting the recordsets, the Data Provider messages went away. Of course, that introduced other issues, but that's another story...and of course, I still don't understand WHY doing this made a difference...anyone else?